# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException while using protocol-selenium plugin nutch

Tags: ssl, selenium-webdriver, nutch

I am trying to index this [page](https://us.vwr.com/store/product?partNum=68300-353) using Apache Nutch selenium driver but when running parsechecker command it is throwing SSLHandShake exception.

```
bin/nutch parsechecker -Dplugin.includes='protocol-selenium|parse-tika' -Dselenium.grid.binary=/usr/bin/geckodriver -Dselenium.enable.headless=true  -followRedirects -dumpText https://us.vwr.com/store/product?partNum=68300-353
```

---

```
Fetch failed with protocol status: exception(16), lastModified=0: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

When i have tried protocol-httpclient, Nutch is able to crawl content of page but it is not crawling dynamic content as httpclient is not support it. i have also tried protocol-interactiveselenium as well but with this also i am getting SSL handshake issue.

I have downloaded certificate and installed in JRE as well, but still facing same issue.

Version: Nutch 1.16

**Update-1**

Now when i checked hadoop.log, it is showing below error in log file:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is related to [NUTCH-2649](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2649). For `protocol-httpclient` and `protocol-http` currently, Nutch has a dummy `TrustManager` for the connection (i.e we don't validate the certificates). As described in NUTCH-2649 `protocol-selenium` does not use the custom `TrustManager` and it tries to properly validate the certificate.

That being said, adding the certificate to the JVM should solve the issue for this specific domain. Perhaps selenium is not having access to the list of allowed certificates.

Comment: i have added certificate to JVM but still getting same issue.i am trying this on Ubantu.